# Object tracking in video

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, tracking

I'm trying to tracking people in the video. But I can not find a suitable algorithm that would behave similarly to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qjr3RYecv3U.

I tried template matching in combination with optical flow, but always lose the tracked object if it overlaps another object. Could someone recommend a suitable method for tracking?

I am using Python and OpenCV.

Comment: What's your [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system)? Are you using [OpenCV Contrib Tracking](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/tracking) module via Python wrapper? See [GitHub examples](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=tracking+opencv&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) and [this tutorial](http://derek.simkowiak.net/motion-tracking-with-python/).

Comment: OS: Linux Mint 17.2
OpenCv: 2.4.8 without OpenCv Contrib Tracking

Comment: If you're trying to implement object tracking by yourself, you can see how object tracking was implemented in [OpenCV Contrib Tracking module](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/tracking). [OpenCV's README](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/tracking/README.md) states that there are implemented *5 different visual object tracking techniques* mentioned [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/tracking/doc/tracker_algorithms.html#tracker-algorithms).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object tracking in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256700/object-tracking-in-python)

Comment: OpenCV Contrib Tracking is good but i need remove tracked object from tracking. Do you know how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

The [results](http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2017/results) of the ILSVRC 2017 competition were released yesterday (July 17, 2017).  The winner in the two tracking categories, Task 3c (Object detection/tracking from video with provided training data) and Task 3d (Object detection/tracking from video with additional training data), was this team:

Jiankang Deng(1), Yuxiang Zhou(1), Baosheng Yu(2), Zhe Chen(2), Stefanos Zafeiriou(1), Dacheng Tao(2), (1)Imperial College London, (2)University of Sydney

Here are their publications, source code, and a presentation:
[1] [Deep Feature Flow for Video Recognition](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07715) 
Xizhou Zhu, Yuwen Xiong, Jifeng Dai, Lu Yuan, and Yichen Wei, IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR), 2017.

[2] [Flow-Guided Feature Aggregation for Video Object Detection](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.10025.pdf), Xizhou Zhu, Yujie Wang, Jifeng Dai, Lu Yuan, and Yichen Wei. Arxiv tech report, 2017.

Presentation
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0rMHE6ehGw

Source Code
https://github.com/msracver/Deep-Feature-Flow

The code has the following prerequisites:

- Python 3.2.0+
- Microsoft's MXNet
- Cython
- OpenCV (Python bindings)

Their code requires a GPU with at least 6GB of memory.

Another option is [ROLO](http://guanghan.info/projects/ROLO/).  The author is Guanghan Ning and he uses You Only Look Once (YOLO) for detection and uses TensorFlow to implement LSTMs for tracking.

His published a paper:
[Spatially Supervised Recurrent Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual Object Tracking](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.05781), IEEE International Symposium on Circuits and Systems, 2017

His code is here: https://github.com/Guanghan/ROLO

Project page: http://guanghan.info/projects/ROLO/

Prerequisites:

- Python 2.7 or 3.3+
- TensorFlow
- Scipy
- OpenCV (Python bindings)

Some videos of his work:

- [ROLO example on unseen sequence: Surfer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qElDUVmYSpY)
- [ROLO example on unseen sequence: Boy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dDsvVEt4ak)
- [ROLO example on unseen sequence: Jumping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7Bxf4guddg)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for some quick code which runs in CPU, take a look at Drew-NF. This is a python implementation of the neural network discussed in the paper [Tubelets with
Convolutional Neural Networks for Object Detection from Videos](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.02532.pdf).
To Run the script you need:

1. Tensorflow
2. OpenCV

[DrewNF Github Repo](https://github.com/DrewNF/Tensorflow_Object_Tracking_Video)